# class that can be compared with ints

Tags: python-3.x, class, types, operator-overloading

I want a class `Inf` such that I can write code like

```
>>> class Inf:
...   pass # TODO
...
>>> Inf > 3
True
```

I know that I can do this

```
>>> class Inf:
...   def __gt__(self, other):
...     return True
...   def __lt__(self, other):
...     return False
...   def __eq__(self, other):
...     return type(self) == type(other)
...
>>> inf = Inf()
>>> inf > 3
True
```

But I want the **class itself** to be able to be compared with `int`s, not an **instance of it** to be able to be compared with `int`s.

I want to be able to do `Inf > 3 # True`, not `Inf() > 3 # True`.

This is my attempt, which doesn't work:

```
>>> class Inf:
...   @classmethod
...   def __gt__(cls, other):
...     return True
...   ... # more classmethods
...
>>> Inf > 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: type() < int()
```

Halp plz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost impossible cause `Inf` is an instance of `type`, therefore what you want is to compare an instance of `type` and an `int`, so method `__gt__()` of `Inf` is useless in such a case.
And I don't know is there any reason to avoid use:

```
class Inf:
    @classmethod
    def __gt__(cls, other):
        return True
inf = Inf()
print(inf > 3)
```

So, if you indeed need a `class` to be compared, try write a subclass of `type` which has the the overwritten `__gt__()` method:

```
class MyType(type):
    def __gt__(cls,other):
        return True
Inf = MyType('Inf',(),{})
print(Inf > 3)
```